# Translate homepage meta Title and description

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, meta-tags

I have a [Multilingual Drupal 7 site](http://landberg.at) using [i18](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n).

But how do I get my homepage meta Title and description translated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [variable translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113374) module.

> The Variable translation module, part of the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)
>   (i18n) package, allows you to translate text and settings that are
>   stored in Drupal as variables. These variables include text such as
>   'site name' and 'site slogan', as well as settings like 'Default front
>   page' and 'Default 404 page'.

Go to

> admin/config/regional/i18n/variable

and select the variables you would like to translate.
Then translate the string(s) at

> admin/config/system/site-information

Comment: i have that one installed. I use also [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module and set `Global: Front page` meta settings. But how do i translate those meta settings?

Comment: @samiksha.gupta008 (one who suggested edit): repeating the same link twice serves no purpose. If anything, link to i18n project page was missing. And i18n is short name, not code, so using code block made no sense.

Comment: @Meez please check the updated answer :)

Comment: @Potney Switters regarding your updated answer i have in admin/config/system/site-information > E.g. Sitename for all 3 languages different values... But my Title and description is controlled with Metatag module?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your query. You need to create a custom module with using [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) & [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module.

I am refer you to this [LINK](https://www.drupal.org/node/1144856#comment-7914871). Hope you can solve by using this link.

**OR**

Use [Translation Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_table) module.

> UI for quick translation of taxonomies and menus. The i18n module
>   allows for translation of taxonomy terms and menu items, but the
>   process is tedious - you need to look up strings you want to
>   translate, there is no overview of what's already translated etc.

- Goto `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`
- then filter by metatag and it will show all the metatags that you can translate.

Comment: i enabled Translation table module. But when i go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate and filter by Metatag, i don't see any results listed?

Comment: Have you check that LINK which I have mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!metatag!metatag.api.php/function/hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter().
 */
 function mymodule_metatag_metatags_view_alter(&$output, $instance, $options) {
   if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
     $output['title']['#attached']['metatag_set_preprocess_variable'][0][2] = t($output['title']['#attached']['metatag_set_preprocess_variable'][0][2]);
     $output['description']['#attached']['drupal_add_html_head'][0][0]['#value'] = t($output['description']['#attached']['drupal_add_html_head'][0][0]['#value']);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install and enable the Translation table module. Then follow these steps

1.Go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate.

2.Then filter by metatag and it will show all the metatags that you can      translate.
[image]

Comment: i enabled Translation table module. But when i go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate and filter by Metatag, i don't see any results?